# Discrete Math Help with a Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help to prove the following:

Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be any integers. If $a \mid b$, then $a \mid bc$

My brain is in overload and just not working.

Comment: There is no trick here. Just plug in the definition. If you have been working too long, take a break.

Answer (score 1):

If $a \mid b$ then $\exists q \in \mathbb{Z}: aq=b$. So, $aqc=bc$. If you take $Q=qc$ you see that $\exists Q \in \mathbb{Z}: aQ=bc$, therefore, $a \mid bc$.

Now you can prove this one on your own for practicing:

If $a \mid b$ and $c \mid d$ then $ac \mid bd$.

And this one:

If $a \mid b$ and $a \mid c$ then $a \mid bx+cy$ for any $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Just applying definitions should help you prove them straightforwardly.

Answer (score 0):

If $a\mid b$ then $b=an$ for $n\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$.  Then, $bc = (an)c$ and so $a\mid bc$.